# How to reserve Linux's memory for a single driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver

I am running a secure OS in the ARM Trustzone, along side Linux which is running in the "normal" world. Since some part of the RAM is protected by hardware from access by the normal world (using a TZASC), I want to prevent Linux to try to access it otherwise it will crash. I also need a shared buffer between the two world, allocated by Linux. To this purpose, I want to reserve two memory regions, using [this document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/reserved-memory/reserved-memory.txt).

I have two kind of areas:

- the first one is a static one and I don't want to ever touch it
- the second one is a dynamic one and I only want a single driver to be able to modify its content.

Here is an extract of my device tree:

```
    reserved-memory {
    #address-cells = <2>;
            #size-cells = <2>;
            ranges;

            /* global autoconfigured region for contiguous allocations */
            linux,cma {
                    compatible = "shared-dma-pool";
                    reusable;
                    reg = <0 0xa0000000 0 0x14000000>;
                    linux,cma-default;
            };

            /* First range, static, that I don't want anyone to touch */
            reserved_static: mymem@0xc0000000 {
                    compatible = "mymem,reserved-memory";
                    reg = <0 0xc0000000 0 0x08000000>;
                    no-map;
            };

            /* Second range, limited to a single driver */
            reserved_dynamic: shared {
                    compatible = "mymem,memory-shared";
                    size = <0 0x08000000>;
                    alignment = <0 0x200000>;
                    alloc-ranges = <0 0xc8000000 0 0x38000000>;
            };
    };

    mydev {
        compatible  = "mydev,mydev";
        memory-region = <&reserved_dynamic>;
    };
```

I can access the device tree information from my driver code, and I would like to prevent *any* access to the static memory range (I think I got that one covered with the `no-map` attribute), and also that only my driver is able to access the dynamic one.

Is this possible, and how can I achieve it ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"static"* and *"dynamic"*?  Allocation?  What's the purpose of reserving a memory region that cannot be accessed?

Comment: @sawdust I updated the question: I have a secure OS + Linux (see ARM Trustzone design) and I want to prevent Linux from crashing because it has accessed some forbidden memory range (reserved by hw to the secure OS) and I also need a shared buffer, which should be below 4 Gb because my secure OS is 32 bits but the board is aarch64